# How to get the file using relative path (argument) in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, path, fs

I want to get the files using `myFunction()`

how to get the file if user pass a relative path as function argument

**../somewhere/index.js**

```js
import {myFunction} from "../pathTo/app.js";
    
myFunction("../relative/path/file.txt");
```

**app.js**

```js
export const myFunction = (path) => {
   fs.readFile(path); //=> How to get the file here
};
```

Comment: You could use `__dirname + "/relativ/path"` or something like `const path = require('path'); path.resolve(../relative/path/file.txt")` to get the absolute path

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have a terminal executing the **node.js** file and the terminal is open at

```
/home/user
```

And the path of **node.js** file is

```
/home/user/test
```

Then we can get the relative path to a file in two different ways

```
var path = require("path");

let path1=path.join('__dirname','../relative/path/file.txt');
fs.readFile(path1);
let path2=path.join('./','../relative/path/file.txt');
fs.readFile(path1);
```

Here **'__dirname'** represents the actual path where the current node.js file being executed is present i.e.

> /home/user/test

and **'./'** represents the path from where the node.js file is being executed i.e.

> /home/user

Path where the terminal is currently at and executing the given node.js file

Hence

> **path1 will represent path relative to the directory that contains the node.js file**

```
path1='/home/user/test/../relative/path/file.txt'
     = '/home/user/test/relative/path/file.txt'
```

> **path2 will represent the path realtive to the place from where terminal is being run**

```
path2='/home/user/../relative/path/file.txt'
     ='/home/relative/path/file.txt'
```

[Difference between __dirname and ./ in Node.js](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-__dirname-and-in-node-js/)

[Path Node.js Documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html)

Comment: What if my app.js is a npm package, and user can import myFunction to there code and call the function with passing a relative path of there file. I need to get the file and process it. How to get the file in that case ? Thanks

Comment: In that case you can use 
**let actual_path=path.reslove('__dirname')**
In Index.js file that will give you actual path of index.js file and can pass it as another argument to myfunction

Comment: Is there any non node solution? client side in the browser solution?